# How do I make a separate folder for my app and store images there? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey guys so I wish to make a new folder for my app under Android and then store images there which will be retrieved for future use.
Here's what I have tried -

```
Future<bool> LocalImage(String url) async {
    Directory directory;
    var dio = Dio();
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage) &&
            // access media location needed for android 10/Q
            await _requestPermission(Permission.accessMediaLocation) &&
            // manage external storage needed for android 11/R
            await _requestPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage))  {
          directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()) as Directory;
          String newPath = "";
          print(directory);
          List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
          for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
            String folder = paths[x];
            if (folder != "Android") {
              newPath += "/" + folder;
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
          newPath = newPath + "/Verif-ID";

          if (await Directory(newPath).exists()){
            ;
          }
          else{ directory = Directory(newPath);
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
          directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }


      if (await directory.exists()) {
        File saveFile = File(directory.path );
        await dio.download(url, saveFile.path,);

        return true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The issues I am currently facing are-
1.It does make a new folder by that name but no download is happening
2. I keep getting the following in my console
`FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.id_me/files' (OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21)`

I understand that this error must mean that a folder of the name already exists but I thought my if conditions were checking that but I guess not. My logics are not the best haha.

This is my first flutter app so I am very sorry if this was a silly doubt.
The URL will be from my firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

Add a file name to a directory path.

> savePath: The path to save the downloading file later. A path with String type, eg "xs.jpg"

```
await dio.download(url, saveFile.path + "/xs.jpg")
```

See [download](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Dio/download.html) for details.